# How to include ' (quote) in EXEC

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following T-SQL code, how can I enclose `@Name` and `P` in quotes?

```
EXEC('xp_cmdshell ''echo IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = ' + @Name + ' AND type = P)>> C:\test.txt'', NO_OUTPUT')`
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @Name varchar(50)='test'

EXEC('xp_cmdshell ''echo IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE name = ''''' + @Name + ''''' AND type = ''''P'''')>> 
C:\test.txt'', NO_OUTPUT')
```

Comment: Won't that end the 1st argument of xp_cmdshell?